# AngularJS - how to get first item in ng-repeat orderby:'title'

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know how to get the first item's data after changing the order in ng-repeat.

I have created the jsfiddle which loads first item of the data.
I'd like get first item after orderBy title.

http://jsfiddle.net/xTJr3/1/

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div data-items></div>
</div>

angular.module('App', []).
// sample data
controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items =[
        {'title': 'Item 3'},
        {'title': 'Item 2'},
        {'title': 'Item 1'}
    ]
}).
directive('items', function(){
    return {
        template: '<span ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:\'title\'">{{item.title}}</span>'+
        '<h1>{{currentItem}}</h1>',
        controller: function($scope){
            // wants to get first item's title after ordered by title.
            // it should be Item 1
            $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[0].title;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to make this works.  Easiest would be using the `orderByFilter` directly in controller, that way both controller & view share the same `items`.

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/3aaTs/)

```
directive('items', function(){
    return {
        template: '<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.title}}</span>'+
        '<h1>{{currentItem}}</h1>',
        controller: function($scope, orderByFilter){  
            $scope.items = orderByFilter($scope.items, 'title');
            $scope.currentItem = $scope.items[0].title;
        }
    }
})
```